# Show drafts assets on Asset Publisher

Tags: liferay, assets, publisher

Is there any way to show on Asset Publisher the assets that are still drafts?

I tried to insert manually the attribute Field.Status on the search query but the results are the same (i.e. no drafts are displayed).

Is this even possible?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no otb feature presenting content in draft or any pending status in portal. We managed to hook this feature by overriding few files in portal to allow seeing such a content depending on a role of users. Hope this helps you get a clue.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on that? What was overridden? I managed to get the Asset Publisher to display the drafts contents but when I click on the content, I get a NoSuchArticleException.

Comment: Here are two files which you should try to modify, if you want to achieve my result: 
- /html/portlet/journal_content/view.jsp
- /html/taglib/ui/journal_article.jsp

Here is service which should be helpful in your implementation "JournalArticle articleLast = JournalArticleServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(articleGroupId, articleId, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_ANY);"

Comment: Thanks. That helped to clarify but it didn't solve it. What liferay version were you using back then? Could you attach as an answer the code snippet?